# What is the meaning of $C^2$ function? (convention in PDE)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In calculus class, I learned that $C^2$ function is twice continuously differentiable function in whatever domain. I am now taking PDE class, and the norm of $C^2$ function is defined as the sum of supremum of derivatives up to second derivatives of the given function. According to this definition, the function not only has to be differentiable, but also its all derivatives have to be bounded in order to belong to $C^2$.

So my question is: is there really two definitions for $C^k$ function? or do I miss something? Thank you!

Comment: The norm is not part of the definition of a $C^2$ function. $C^2$ function only means the function has continuous second derivatives. The norm is something that is defined on top of the function space for use in proofs and so on. Kind of like $\mathbb{R}^2$ is just the space of ordered pairs of real numbers. However you can define a Euclidean norm $\|(x,y)\| = \sqrt{ x^2 + y^2}$ on top of that. The definition of $\mathbb{R}^2$ has properties independent of the norm and its definition does not depend on the norm.

Comment: @Doge Chan Thank you. That clarifies a lot. I've always thought that the functional space is defined by having its norm a finite value.

Comment: You can have function spaces without a norm. You just need the norm to have a metric space which is what enables you to do all the analysis on the space. Otherwise you're limited to just algebra.

Comment: @DogeChan Also, even if your vector space does have a norm on it, it is not true that it is defined by having finite norm, though a lot of examples are defined this way. Just think of $C^0$ with the sup-norm: it is not true that a function is continuous if and only if it is bounded